# LinkedList adding Element

Tags: c, linked-list, rtos, micrium

We have a problem with our LinkedList in C.
When I count how many nodes should be in the list, I always get 1

> LL count: 1

This is the Add, count and get last element of the list code:

```
void addLL(LL * head)
{
LL *newNode;
LL *tail = getLastNode(head);

newNode = malloc(sizeof(LL));
if(newNode != DEF_NULL)
{
    newNode->ID=-1;
    newNode->TCB=-1;
    newNode->next = DEF_NULL;

    if(!head) head = newNode;
    else tail->next = newNode;      
}   
}

LL * getLastNode(LL * head)
{
    LL *temp = head;
    while(temp->next != DEF_NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}

CPU_INT32U countLL(LL * head)
{
    CPU_INT32U elements = 0;
    LL * temp = head;
    while(temp->next != DEF_NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        elements++;
    }
    return elements;
}
```

It's called in this way:

```
addLL(list);
temp = countLL(list);       
Debug_LOG("LL count: %i", temp);
```

where LL * list; is a global variable, and temp is in local scope. 
I hope anyone can see where I went wrong

Greetings,
Sjaak and Gerrit

Comment: are you sure the list is not NULL, you are adding only one element with newNode = malloc(sizeof(LL));

Comment: What is wrong here? If you add one element, the count will be one element only... add more elements to test your `countLL()`

Comment: Sorry, I should have said AddLL is called in a main routine, every second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see several issues in your code :

- you should always protect your linked list operations by **testing if the list pointer is valid** (i.e. not null)
- you cannot allocate a first item to an empty list due to the way you allocate the first new item : you change `head` but the modification won't be propagated outside of the function. **You should pass a "pointer to a list pointer"** (i.e. a `LL**`) that is equivalent to "the address of a `LL*`"; See how I call `addLL()` and how I have modified its prototype and the `head` assignment
- if your list is only one block long, it won't be counted as **you count only if there is a successor**, see how I have modifed the order of the do / while condition

I propose the modified code that works for 1, 2 or any list length (I have just changed the `CPU_INT32U` to `int` to compile quickly with MinGW, I could have typedef'ined):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEF_NULL 0

typedef struct tagL {
    int ID;
    int TCB;
    struct tagL *next;
} LL;

void addLL(LL ** head);
LL * getLastNode(LL * head);
int countLL(LL * head);

void addLL(LL ** head)
{
    LL *newNode;
    LL *tail = getLastNode(*head);

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(LL));
    if(newNode != DEF_NULL)
    {
        newNode->ID=-1;
        newNode->TCB=-1;
        newNode->next = DEF_NULL;

        if(!*head) 
            *head = newNode;
        else 
            tail->next = newNode;      
    }   
}

LL * getLastNode(LL * head)
{
    LL *temp = head;
    if (head){
        while(temp->next != DEF_NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
    return temp;
}

int countLL(LL * head)
{
    int elements = 0;
    LL * temp = head;
    if (head){
        do {
            temp = temp->next;
            elements++;
        } while(temp != DEF_NULL);
    }
    return elements;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    LL *list = 0;

    printf("LL test\n");
    addLL(&list);
    printf("length = %d\n", countLL(list));
    addLL(&list);
    printf("length = %d\n", countLL(list));
    addLL(&list);
    printf("length = %d\n", countLL(list));
}
```

Output :

```
LL test
length = 1
length = 2
length = 3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Seki, it works well now.. I understand the thought of a pointer to a pointer, so you have the address of the pointer.. which will be edited everywhere. My first thought was, it's already a pointer so if I change it there, it will be changed everywhere.. well got the idea now, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Davey: You 're welcome :o) If my answer was helpful, think about selecting it as "the answer" by clicking on the white check sign on the left.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows nothing's wrong whit this function - strange ...

[ideone also shows good output.](http://ideone.com/uwDHg)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LL{
    struct LL *next;
}LL;

LL * getLastNode(LL * head)
{
    LL *temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return temp;
}

void addLL(LL * head)
{
LL *newNode;
LL *tail = getLastNode(head);

newNode = malloc(sizeof(LL));
if(newNode != NULL)
{
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if(!head) head = newNode;
    else tail->next = newNode;      
}   
}

int countLL(LL * head)
{
    int elements = 0;
    LL * temp = head;
    while(temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
        elements++;
    }
    return elements;
}

int main() {
    LL *h = malloc(sizeof(*h));
    addLL(h);
    addLL(h);
    addLL(h);
    printf("%d\n", countLL(h)); // prints 3 as expected
}
```

Comment: `addLL()` is wrong as it cannot add to an empty list, you are cheating by allocating manually a LL in the `main()`...

Answer (score 0):

CPU_INT32U countLL(LL * head){CPU_INT32U elements = 0;LL * temp = head;while(temp->next != DEF_NULL){temp = temp->next;elements++;}return elements;}

in this function you are declaring elements variable as auto
so its storage gets deallocated as soon as function exits , as memory now free to allocate to different variable, so may be overwritten hence previous cvalue gets lost

so to avoid this please use static in declaring variable.....
as static variables memory gets deallocated only after execution of whole program
please try....

Answer (score 0):

```
void addLL(LL * head)
{
LL *newNode;
LL *tail = getLastNode(head);
```

There is a problem here, if (the global) head happens to be NULL, it will be dereferenced by the getLastNode() function:

```
LL * getLastNode(LL * head)
{
    LL *temp = head;
    while(temp->next != DEF_NULL)
```

Here `temp->next != ...` will cause temp to be dereferenced. That would cause NULL pointer dereferences if temp happens to be NULL. (as in the call by the insert function. You could add an extra test (or use pointers to pointers which is cleaner):

```
while(temp && temp->next != DEF_NULL)
```

Update (to show that the pointer to pointer version is cleaner)

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define DEF_NULL NULL
#define CPU_INT32U unsigned

typedef struct link {
        struct link *next;
        } LL;

LL *globhead=NULL;
LL **getTailPP(LL **ppHead);
CPU_INT32U countLL(LL * ptr);
void addLL(LL **ppHead);

void addLL(LL **ppHead)
{
ppHead = getTailPP(ppHead);

*ppHead = malloc(sizeof **ppHead);
    if(*ppHead != DEF_NULL)
    {
        // newNode->ID=-1;
        // newNode->TCB=-1;
        (*ppHead)->next = DEF_NULL;
    }
}

LL **getTailPP(LL **ppHead)
{
    for( ; *ppHead; ppHead = &(*ppHead)->next ) {;}
    return ppHead;
}

CPU_INT32U countLL(LL * ptr)
{
    CPU_INT32U elements = 0;
    for(; ptr != DEF_NULL; ptr=ptr->next) { elements++; }
    return elements;
}

int main()
{
unsigned count;

addLL( &globhead);
count = countLL (globhead);
printf("count = %u\n", count);

addLL( &globhead);
count = countLL (globhead);
printf("count = %u\n", count);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks wildplasser.. you explained the fact of pointer to a pointer.. in my mind it was like: 'I'm already using a pointer, so ill pass the address' but ofcourse, a pointer also needs a pointer. Thanks a lot! also for testing the whole thing.. awesome how much people want to help!!

Comment: If you think about it, the only thing that happens is that a pointer that *was* NULL will be assigned the value of the new element. Whether that pointer is the head pointer or some ->next pointer is not important. It is a pointer to LL, that is what matters. There is only one assignment: a pointer that used to be NULL gets a value.